# How do I register multiple services with a specific interface in Castle Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor

I have the following registration:

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<ITabViewModel>().BasedOn<ITabViewModel>());
```

Two classes:

```
public class StructureDecorationViewModel : NotificationObject, ITabViewModel
{
...
}

public abstract class NotificationObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
...
}
```

And two resolvers:

```
serviceProvider.ResolveAll<System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged>()
serviceProvider.ResolveAll<ITabViewModel>()
```

Both of these Resolvers gives the StructureDecorationViewModel, how can I filter the registration so that I only register the ITabViewModel and not the INotifyPropertyChange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To register against just one interface you would normally use FirstInterface:

```
AllTypes
    .FromAssemblyContaining<ITabViewModel>()
    .BasedOn<ITabViewModel>()
    .WithService
    .FirstInterface();
```

However in this case you would end up with your service registered against INotifyPropertyChanged which is not what you want as it picks the first interface from the base class (Have a look at the ServiceDescriptor class to see what other registrations are available).

What you need is the Select method that allows you to define the type or types you want to register the service against:

```
AllTypes
    .FromAssemblyContaining<ITabViewModel>()
    .BasedOn<ITabViewModel>()
    .WithService
    .Select(typeof(ITabViewModel));
```

However if you want to keep things more generic someone has written an extension method that looks at the service being registered and picks out the first interface on the derived class (http://www.hightech.ir/SeeSharp/windsor-registration-service-interface):

```
public static BasedOnDescriptor FirstInterfaceOnClass(this ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor)
{
   return serviceDescriptor.Select((t, bt) =>
   {
       var baseInterfaces = t.BaseType.GetInterfaces();
       var interfaces = t.GetInterfaces().Except(baseInterfaces);

       return interfaces.Count() != 0 ? new[] {interfaces.First()} : null;
   });
}
```

Which allows you to do this:

```
AllTypes
    .FromAssemblyContaining<ITabViewModel>()
    .BasedOn<ITabViewModel>()
    .WithService
    .FirstInterfaceOnClass();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Both solutions worked fine. I did however still get services from ResolveAll of the type  INotifyPropertyChanged. But this went away after an upgrade to v3 of castle Windsor.